# Properly capitalizing each word within a model's row in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, object, activerecord

I'm working in Ruby and ActiveRecord albeit not full Rails; it's really just Sinatra serving the backend. I have an Artist model, that only contains an id and a name. What I'm aiming to do is capitalize (by use of *titleize*) each name, such that if any word follows a space it's to be capitalized.

I can make this happen with names in an array (`self.cleanup` works) but I can't do it within an object. (`self.fixer` doesn't) I have pictures below of each function's Pry output.

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  has_many :genres, through: :songs
  has_many :reviews, through: :songs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :genres, :songs

  # stores an array of all the artists' names
  def self.names
    all.pluck(:name)
  end

  # cleans up the names of each Artist, capitalizes all
  def self.cleanup
    unique_array = self.names.uniq
    unique_array.map { |string| string.titleize }
  end

  # capitalizes each name within the Artist model
  def self.fixer
    self.all.each do |artist|
      artist.name.titleize
    end
  end
end
```

[Here is my Artist.fixer function, which doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbmAd.png)

[Here is my Artist.cleanup function, which does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPd70.png)

Comment: the `each` method does not return the result of the block. Use `map` instead of `each`

Comment: I replaced `each` with `map` but that just gives me the same result as `self.cleanup` -- my goal is to still get the full spectrum of the Artist object, showcasing `id` and `name` for each but with the `name` value capitalized properly.

Comment: can you give an example of what you wish to achieve, b/c I don't understand what you have said.

Comment: For sure -- so if you check the two attached pictures I have in the post, what I want is to have the same output as in the first picture BUT to have only the names be the same as in the second picture. 

But for total ouptut, when I do `Artist.all` I want to see the output of the first picture but with each name value capitalized.

Comment: For example, the name values for id: {15, 16, 18, 19} should be capitalized in the first picture but they're not

Comment: You should be aware the titelize is very naive approach at capitalization and will mess up names like DeVal or le Carré. This doesn't sound like a great idea if proper capitalization is the goal.

Comment: No doubt -- if you have any suggestions on a proper method, I'll take them. Step 1 for me is accessing each name value, then Step 2 is figuring out the proper approach. I'll take any useable tips!

Comment: `titelize` doesn't mutate the string its called on - it just returns a new string. There is a `titelize!` method which does - but thats pretty smelly.

Comment: It would  be better to just add a `titelized_name` instance method to the class and use that instead.

Comment: I didn't look at the pics you linked. Generally not regarded as good practice on SO.

Comment: Duly noted  for future posts -- with that in mind though, do the pictures clarify what I'm looking for?

Comment: @max thank you! Will look into building that -- I can see how that's a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

When calling

```
self.all.each { |artist| artist.name.titleize }
```

Ruby will iterate over all `artists` and call `titleize` on their name. But `titleize` will not change the string on which it is called, it only returns a titleized version of the string. Because you do not store the returned titleized string it is not persisted after the `each` call.

Instead, change your method to this and reassign the titleized version to the artist's name:

```
def self.fixer
  self.all.each do |artist|
    artist.name = artist.name.titleize
  end
end
```

Please note that this only changes the artist's name in the array returned from the `fixer` method. it does not update and permanently fix the name in the database. Therefore you might want to consider fixing names before saving the name into the database. Then you would not need to fix it each time again when reading a record from the database.

Comment: Thank you @spickerman -- I actually managed to figure it out. Posted in the original body for future devs but yes you are right on the titleize not saving itself. Went with a before_save :title_fixer function.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, as a two-stepper for anyone confused reading this in posterity.

(1) Defining the function, hereby called title_fixer.
(2) Putting a before_save :title_fixer header within my class.

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  has_many :genres, through: :songs
  has_many :reviews, through: :songs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :genres, :songs
  before_save :title_fixer

  ## corrects the title capitilzation
  ## always launched before an artist saves

  def title_fixer
    ## add a case to capitalize after [&, -, /]
    self.name = self.name.split(/ |\_/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
  end
end
```

Only thing left to do is work with the regex to include cases for "&", "-", and "/" -- for example to capitalize "Hip-hop -> Hip-Hop" and "R&b/soul -> R&B/Soul". Otherwise, it seems to work well.